# Excluir o Ignorar un include

Tags: php

Buenas noches, estoy realizando un proyecto donde debo consultar y posteriormente modificar unos datos, pero se me presenta la siguiente situación:

1. Tengo el Query de la consulta y luego de este, un include donde almaceno la forma en la cual se visualizaran los datos.
2. Pero al momento de consultar para modificar, el include anterior no me sirve y quisiera ignorarlo para luego agregar otro.

La pregunta es: ¿Existe la manera de hacer eso? o ¿deberé copiar y pegar el código y anexar el nuevo include?

[image: Imagen del include de la consulta]

Como verán en la imagen, ese include es el que me sirve para el formato de la consulta, mas no me sirve para el formato de modificación, pero como el codigo de consulta es el mismo, ¿puedo excluir ese include o debo copiar todo de nuevo en otro archivo?

Comment: No hace falta que hagas un include. En el mismo archivo php podes agregar todo lo necesario y utilizar condiciones como if...else

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas tener una forma de identificar el tipo de consulta y me imagino que viene en un `POST` o algo así, entonces necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

```
if($_POST['tipo_consulta'] == 'consulta'){
  include_once "casoConstanciaAlumno.php";
}else{
  include_once "casoInversoPersonaAjena.php";
}
```

¡No olvides escapar tus inputs antes de usarlos en el código!

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia que es escapar? Lo solvente cambiando la forma en que busco los datos y listo ya funcionó, no necesite colocar el condicional.

Comment: Con escapar se refiere a eliminar los caracteres especiales como ( / ' , ; " para evitar ataques del tipo XSS

Comment: Estás usando datos de `$_POST` directo en tu query, puedo enviar en ese `POST['cedulaAlumno]` el texto `0;DELETE FROM cedulaAlumno;` por ejemplo y borro toda tu tabla aunque las posibilidades para explotar son amplias. Debes eliminar esta posibilidad usando queries parametrizadas o escapando el input de query. Revisa la función [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)